# How can I use another viewer in AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced

Tags: perl, viewer, expert-system

I tried to use [`AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced`](https://metacpan.org/module/AI%3a%3aExpertSystem%3a%3aAdvanced). I read in documentation that I can use another viewers. You can see it there:

> **viewer**
>   Is the object AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced will be using for
>   printing  what is happening and for interacting with the user (such as
>   asking  the asked_facts).
>
> This is practical if you want to use a viewer object that is not 
>   provided by AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced::Viewer::Factory.
>
> **viewer_class**
>   Is the the class name of the viewer.
>   use the viewers  AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced::Viewer::Factory offers,
>   in this case you  can pass the object or only the name of your
>   favorite viewer.

or in this module I find this:

> Offers different views, so user can interact with the expert system
>   via a terminal or with a friendly user interface.

example of source is:

```
my $ai = AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced->new(
                    viewer_class => 'terminal',
                    knowledge_db => $yaml_kdb,
                    initial_facts => ['I'],
                    verbose => 1);
```

Can I use as viewer_class my browser or some CGI interface??? When yes how to use it??? I didnt find any example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use other viewer class than terminal in AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656369/how-to-use-other-viewer-class-than-terminal-in-aiexpertsystemadvanced)

Comment: How long are you planning to keep asking this question? Maybe the awful truth is that SO cannot help you. Maybe you should finally try to contact the author of that module and get some expert advice that way.

Comment: I deleted it. It has less informations

Comment: Author didnt answered me. I wrote him. But I dont know if the email I have is his.

Comment: I dont want to ask anything... I edit it only to answer me goals that causes is in initial_facts. When some causes isnt in initial_facts this goal is not printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write your own "Viewer" class. Create a new module that extends from `AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced::Viewer::Base` and implement each method that has a stub in that base class.
The source and documentation of [`AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced::Viewer::Base'](https://metacpan.org/source/PFISCHER/AI-ExpertSystem-Advanced-0.03/lib/AI/ExpertSystem/Advanced/Viewer/Base.pm) will prove to be helpful in this task.

**Update**

To write your own viewer class, create a file that looks something like this:

```
package My::AI::Viewer;
use Moose;
extends 'AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced::Viewer::Base';

sub debug {
    # your implementation goes here
}
```

...
When you are done with that class, I suppose you can pass its name to the constructor of the expert system module under the `viewer_class` key.

Comment: something like this?
my $viewer = AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced::Viewer::Base->new();
my $ai = AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced->new(
        viewer_class => $viewer,
        knowledge_db => $yaml_kdb,
        initial_facts => $text,
        verbose => 1
        );

Comment: There are no parameters you need to pass to Viewer::Base::new because you will not call that method. See my updated answer.

Comment: could you help me with it? I dont have a lot of experience with it...
I tried something...

Comment: No, I cannot. Please do yourself a favor and try to learn perl first. There is no way around that. Read the [Modern Perl Book](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/), it's free and really good. Try not to think too much about any ExpertSystems running in a CGI evnironment while you do.

Comment: Can't locate object method "new" via package "AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced::Viewer::Expert" at C:/Perl/site/lib/AI/ExpertSystem/Advanced/Viewer/Factory.pm line 29.

Comment: but how can i execute expert system and the result of it print on CGI website??? There is a need to run it in other viewer class or it can run via terminal?